# Slim: is it possible to nest a UL within a paragraph with text content?

Tags: html, slim, nested

What I am looking to achieve is this:

```
<p class="parent">Paragraph text
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
 </ul>
</p>
```

When I try

```
p.parent
  | Paragraph text
  ul
    li One
    li Two
```

It produces

```
<p class="parent">Paragraph text</p>
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to achieve the desired nesting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While nesting a `<ul>` within a `<p>` element is invalid HTML (so no, you can't do that), you can emulate it using, for example, `<span>` elements:

```
<p>Paragraph text <span>First span</span><span>Second span</span></p>
```

With the CSS:

```
p span {
    display: block;
    counter-increment: spanCount;
    position: relative;
}

p span::before {
    content: counter(spanCount);
    margin-right: 0.4em;
    width: 2em;
    text-align: right;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/c4ncfav4/).

References:

- '[Generated content, automatic numbering and lists.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html)'

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll stick to valid HTML and style the UL element accordingly.